# SQL Instruction - set sum, product,

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

how to write sql instruction for:

1. r U s
2. r ∩ s
3. r - s
4. s - r

?
i can not find enything about how to write this :(

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You probably should read up on MySQL's `UNION`, `WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT b FROM c)` and other query constructs. You may want to try a few things and [edit] your question to show your query code.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for `UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `MINUS`. You will need to read up on these to understand how they apply to your question.

Answer (score 0):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html for more information.

You always need to use some SQL command with expressions like [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html), [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html), etc. Sending pure `r ∩ s` to a server won't work.